# Should I add class attributes to Angular component selector tags

Tags: css, angular, angular2-template, angular-components

I'd like to add class directly to selector in Angular 5. Something like this:

```
<myapp-selector class="myclass"></myapp-selector>
```

I've been searching for a while now, and I found some solutions like using `host` of `@Component`. But I can't find a definitive answer on the concrete question.

Is it safe and is it considered a bad practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach would be apply stlye/class inside your component as container, But you can add classes to the component as well.

Comment: But why? May it lead to inconsistencies or odd behavior?

Comment: IMO no inconsistencies or odd behavior, But this is not a recommended approach.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this depends really on what you're trying to achieve.

Simply adding a class to a component, is done by just adding it to the tag statically, just as you've already mentioned.

Adding a class *conditionally* can be done in multiple ways, one of which is using `@HostBinding()` or the component's `host` property

```
@Component({
  ...
})
class SomeComponent {

  @HostBinding('class.someClassName') shouldAddClass: boolean;

}
```

Or

```
@Component({
  host: {
    '[class.active]': 'somePropertyName'
  }
})
class SomeComponent {
  somePropertyName: boolean;
}
```

Now, the `active` class will be added when the property is `true` and remove when it's `false`.

Another alternative is using `[ngClass]` directive, which essentially does the same, just that the consumer of the component decides when class are being added and removed:

```
<some-component [ngClass]="{ active: somePropertyThatsEitherTrueOrFalse }">
```